Etheruem Account Generation, pbkdf2
use crypto::hmac::Hmac;
use crypto::mac::Mac;
use crypto::pbkdf2::pbkdf2;
use crypto::sha2::Sha512;
// crypto is an external crate, "rust-crypto"

pub fn pbkdf2_key_stretching(mnemonic_code: &str, passphrase: &str) -> String {
    // PBKDF2 stretches the mnemonic and salt parameters using 2,048 rounds of hashing with the HMAC-SHA512 algorithm, producing a 512-bit value as its final output.
    // That 512-bit value is the seed!
    // It makes it costly (in computation) to try more than a few thousand passphrase and mnemonic combinations, while the number of possible derived seeds is vast (2512, or about 10154)—far bigger than the number of atoms in the visible universe (about 1080).
    println!("Begin seed production.");
    // Create the salt: "mnemonic" + passphrase
    let salt = format!("mnemonic{}", passphrase);

    // Buffer for the output (64 bytes for the 512-bit seed)
    let mut seed = [0u8; 64];

    // Use PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA512 with 2048 iterations
    pbkdf2(
        &mut Hmac::new(Sha512::new(), mnemonic_code.as_bytes()), // Mnemonic (password)
        salt.as_bytes(),                                   // Salt ("mnemonic" + passphrase)
        2048,                                              // Number of iterations
        &mut seed                                          // Output buffer for the seed
    );

    hex::encode(seed)
}

Hi, I'm trying to create a library to create ethereum accounts using rust. I'd like to check if the above code is accurate.
mnemonic_code is the 12-24  seperated words in a single String and passphrase is just the input String by the user.
Detailed Explanation on why the line:
&mut Hmac::new(Sha512::new(), mnemonic_code.as_bytes()), // Mnemonic (password) is correct will be great. I'm particularly unsure about this part. I mean why can't it be (mnemonic_code | passphrase).as_bytes() (concatination)
Simply put, I do not understand how does the salt work hahaha.
If this is right i will move on to work on the Signing Keys and Withdrawal keys.
FYI: I made a test based on https://iancoleman.io/bip39/#english and it produces the same result.

It is a bit out of scope to ask for a security audit. BIP039 has a test vectors in their definition that you could use to validate the code https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki. I'm not a rustacean but & mut is passing ownership of the result of calling Hmac::new() to pbkdf2. In any case I'd recommend to ask programing question at stackoverflow.com or the more rust specialized forum.
